# Playa upgrade from 3.0.9 to 4.4.3 missing relationship data

Tags: playa, database, upgrade

I just upgraded EE from 2.1 to 2.6.1, then upgraded Playa from 3.0.9 to 4.4.3.

I realized I had to rewrite the syntax in the templates. That wasn't fun. But the real issue I am having is the missing data.

Or I assume the data is there in the old location (exp_realtionships or exp_channel_data perhaps) just the new Playa is looking for it elsewhere (exp_playa_relationships ??).

Playa seems to be working I added new relationships and they showd up both in the CMS and on the site.

Can anyone give me a clue on how I can restore the Playa relationships with this new setup?

Reentering the data manually would take a a few days for 2 or 3 people!

Thanks,
Luke

Comment: This sounds like a job for support@pixelandtonic.com! Also, I hope you have your DB backup and whatnot :)